# Lindelof's Theorem And Second Countable Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a second countable topological space and let a non empty open set $G$ can be written as a union of a class of $G_i$ of open sets, then $G$ can be written as a countable union of $G_i$'s.

It is given that
$$G = \bigcup G_i.$$
Now for any $x \in G$ we have $x \in G_{i_0}$. Now as $X$ is a second countable topological space and hence it has a countable base say
$$B_1, B_2, .........$$
Now as $x \in G_{i_0}$, so there is some $B_{n_0}$ such that
$$x \in B_{n_0} \subset G_{i_0}.$$
And as $x$ is an arbitrary element of $G$ so we have
$$G \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_{n_k}.$$
Also for each $B_{n_k}$ there exists a $G_{i_k}$ such that
$$B_{n_k} \subset G_{i_k}$$
with the above property and hence we have
$$G \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_{n_k} \subset \bigcup^{\infty}_{k=1}G_{i_k} \subset \bigcup G_i = G.$$
And hence we get
$$G = \bigcup^{\infty}_{k=1}G_{i_k}.$$
And hence $G$ can be written as a countable union of $G_i$'s.

> Is My Proof Correct??

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the result is correct, but both the result and your proof are written badly enough that they are unnecessarily hard to follow. The result that you want to prove is this:

> Let $X$ be a second countable space and $G=\bigcup_{i\in I}G_i$ a non-empty open set, where each $G_i$ is also an open set. Then there is a countable $I_0\subseteq I$ such that $G=\bigcup_{i\in I_0}G_i$.

(Note that it is incorrect to write $G=\bigcup G_i$: $\bigcup G_i$ actually means $\bigcup_{A\in G_i}A$, the set of all elements of elements of $G_i$. Of course here the elements of $G_i$ are just points of the space $X$, so this doesn’t actually make much sense, and most readers will realize that you actually mean $\bigcup_{i\in I}G_i$, but it’s better to be accurate and clear.)

The best place to start your proof is by identifying the countable base that you’re going to use.

> $X$ is second countable, so let $\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countable base for $X$.

Now for each $x\in G$ you want to choose a member of the base that contains $x$ and is a subset of some $G_i$. The clearest way to do this is to name that member in a way that shows its association with the point $x$.

> For each $x\in G$ there are an $n(x)\in\Bbb N$ and an $i(x)\in I$ such that $x\in B_{n(x)}\subseteq G_{i(x)}$. Clearly $$G\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in G}B_{n(x)}\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in G}G_{i(x)}\subseteq G\,,$$ so $$G=\bigcup_{x\in G}B_{n(x)}=\bigcup_{x\in G}G_{i(x)}\,.$$

Now comes the one bit that’s slightly tricky to do right. Our base is countable, so there are only countably many different sets $B_{n(x)}$, but there might be uncountably many different sets $G_{i(x)}$: there might be distinct points $x,y\in G$ such that $n(x)=n(y)$, but $i(x)\ne i(y)$. Here’s one way to fix that.

> Let $M=\{n(x):x\in G\}$, for each $m\in M$ let $x_m\in G$ be such that $n(x_m)=m$, and let $i_m=i(x_m)$. Then $I_0=\{i_m:m\in M\}$ is a countable subset of $I$, and $$G=\bigcup_{x\in G}B_{n(x)}=\bigcup_{m\in M}B_m\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I_0}G_i\subseteq G\,,$$ so $G=\bigcup_{i\in I_0}G_i$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the proof is correct. Maybe you could be more clear about what $(n_k)$ is: for every $x ∈ G$ you have $n_0$ depending on $x$. You collect all these $n_0$'s and enumerate them by $(n_k)$. So it would be easier to pick for every $x ∈ G$ a basic set $B_x$ and then just say that the collection $\{B_x: x ∈ G\}$ is countable, and possibly enumerate this collection.

Another pedantic note: $⋃G_i$ can mean $⋃_{i ∈ I} G_i$ as well as $⋃_{A ∈ G_i} A$, so I'd prefer to write at least $⋃_i G_i$.